# Solving a Directed Graph with Recursion

Tags: c#, sql-server, recursion, graph, recursive-query

I'm working on a project that builds flight routes from airport to airport. For example, if someone wants to travel from LAX to JFK, I'd like to return all possible paths from LAX to JFK (with a maximum of n connections). I've been working on converting this example to MS SQL using a recursive CTE (it's the last example in the documentation): [http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafyrecursivequeries.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafyrecursivequeries.htm)

I've been able to duplicate the results, which was great at first. However, performing set based recursion on about 20 records is A LOT faster than performing the same task on a few hundred thousand records (real world direct flights).

So here's my question: can anyone help me figure out a faster method for finding a flight path from one airport to another? I'm building this thing form the ground up using MS SQL and .NET, but am open to using just about anything to get the results returned quickly (set based recursion, iterations (in any language), etc.).

Ideally, I'd like to have the results returned just as quickly as Google Flights returns data (https://www.google.com/flights/).

Here's what I have so far with my rCTE in MS SQL. Note: it just creates ALL possible paths from New York. To narrow it down to all flights from New York to, say, Paris, we would need to change the last line of the query to FROM destinations WHERE arrival = 'Paris'.

Create a test table, FLIGHTS:

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS (DEPARTURE nvarchar(20),
                      ARRIVAL nvarchar(20), 
                      CARRIER nvarchar(15),
                      FLIGHT_NUMBER nvarchar(5), 
                      PRICE decimal(18, 0))
```

Insert data into the test table:

```
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('New York', 'Paris', 'Atlantic', '234', 400)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Chicago', 'Miami', 'NA Air', '2334', 300)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('New York', 'London', 'Atlantic', '5473', 350)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('London', 'Athens'  , 'Mediterranean', '247', 340)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Athens', 'Nicosia' , 'Mediterranean', '2356', 280) 
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Paris', 'Madrid' , 'Euro Air',  '3256', 380)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Paris', 'Cairo' , 'Euro Air', '63', 480)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Chicago', 'Frankfurt', 'Atlantic', '37', 480)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Frankfurt', 'Moscow', 'Asia Air', '2337', 580)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Frankfurt', 'Beijing', 'Asia Air',  '77', 480) 
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Moscow', 'Tokyo', 'Asia Air', '437', 680)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Frankfurt', 'Vienna', 'Euro Air', '59', 200)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Paris', 'Rome', 'Euro Air', '534', 340)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Miami', 'Lima', 'SA Air', '5234', 530)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('New York', 'Los Angeles', 'NA Air', '84', 330)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Los Angeles', 'Tokyo', 'Pacific Air', '824', 530)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Tokyo', 'Hong Kong', 'Asia Air', '94', 330)
INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES('Washington', 'Toronto', 'NA Air', '104', 250)
```

And here's the rCTE:

```
WITH

destinations (origin, departure, arrival, flight_count, itinerary) AS    
    (
        SELECT a.departure, a.departure, a.arrival, 1, CAST(a.departure + ', ' + a.arrival AS VARCHAR(2000))
                FROM [FLIGHTS] a
                WHERE a.departure = 'New York'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT r.origin, b.departure, b.arrival, r.flight_count + 1, CAST(r.itinerary + ', ' + b.arrival AS VARCHAR(2000))
                FROM destinations r, [FLIGHTS] b
                WHERE r.arrival = b.departure
                -- prevent cycles by making sure the new arrive airport is not already listed in the itinerary
                and CAST(r.itinerary AS VARCHAR(2000)) NOT LIKE '%' + b.arrival + '%'
                -- the itinerary is a csv str so we can limit the number of hops here
                and (LEN(CAST(r.itinerary AS VARCHAR(2000))) - LEN(REPLACE(CAST(r.itinerary AS VARCHAR(2000)), ',', ''))) < 3
    )

SELECT origin, departure, arrival, flight_count, itinerary 
    FROM destinations
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This looks like an ideal candidate for a graph database like Neo4j. The cities would be loaded as nodes and the flights as edges (relationships). Finding routes between nodes with a maximum number of hops is then trivial and fast.

Comment: @SteveFord I just installed neo4j. It looks awesome! NoSQL has always been something I've wanted to mess with, and now seems like a really good time to dive in. I'll try both the relational method as well as the graph db (neo4j) way and report back here when I get to the end of the road. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help, take a look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#match-all-shortest-paths for an example of finding the shortest path between two nodes. If you're using C# you can use Neo4jClient http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/Home to load the nodes and edges and perform the cypher queries. Take a look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#match-variable-length-relationships for finding nodes a variable number of hops away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're some trivial observations for you:

1. You will never be able to optimize this without using proper indexing, i.e. at the minimum keys needs to be indexed.
2. `NOT LIKE '%' + b.arrival + '%'` is not going to work fast (it's hard to index this kind of expressions). A different way of checking for already listed airports is needed, perhaps storing the items in temporary tables.
3. A different way of limiting the number of hops is required. Since you just need three hops, you might as well go with 3 joins instead of recursion, that's going to be much faster.

The list could go on and on; building something as fast as Google Flights is **not easy**.

Comment: Addition to @Serge's suggestions, you can try SQL CLR by putting this in a udf.[Read this](http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/comparing-simple-efficiencies-tsql-udf-sqclr-udf-splitting-strings/)

Comment: @serge Thank you so much for your ideas; you were absolutely right about recursion being overkill for this problem. I tried multiple joins (0 joins for direct flights, 1 join for 1 stop and 2 joins for 2 stops) and without any indexing whatsoever, regarding CPU Time, I'm getting about 0 ms for direct flights, 188 ms for 1 stop and 7457 ms for 2 stops. (With the rCTE I manually stopped the query after 6 hours!) Also, since we don't have to worry about cycles with the joins, your #2 concern is solved. After weeks of research, I'm finally at a solid platform. Thank you so much!

Comment: @GayanSanjeewa That link is awesome! Thank you. SQLCLR will definitely come in handy with this project.

Comment: @BrentBarbata It's great to know it worked out for you. Good luck and all the best!